# is bytecode faster than any executable code(.exe etc)?

Tags: java

i am confused about bytecode.

suppose my code is

```
class Simple{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
  system.out.print("hello Java!");
}
```

let it is compile in java compiler then it to be a **Simple.class**

and

```
 int main(){
          print("hello Java!");
          }
```

after compiling it genarate sample.exe
what is faster 
sample.exe or sample.class

Comment: Do you want to know how java bytecodes works? or if java is faster than c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the quality of the implementation of the respective solutions - it's perfectly possible that a GOOD byte-code engine will beat a poorly written compiler, but a badly implemented byte-code engine will definitely be slower than a high quality native compiler.

A good optimiźing native compiler will often beat a compiler that produce byte-code, but there are some decent just-in-time compilers that do a VERY good job on bytecode too - with the added advantage of being able to understand what is "hot" and "cold" paths of the code through profiling information, something that requires at least one extra step in a C or C++ compiler - running some representative sample code to gather information, and then feeding that back to the compiler for "profile guided optimisation".

If the byte-code implementation is simply a byte-code interpreter (not a "just-in-time compiler"), one would expect to see better performance from a native compiled piece of code. But modern Java "byte code interpreters" nearly always have a JIT compiler built in.

Answer (score 3):

Bytecode is like instruction set for the JVM. Whatever code you are writing is converted into byte code by the Java compiler for easier execution. It's similar to using a translator, to convey your code in a way which could be understood by the interpreter. So whatever piece of code you write is converted into a standard form of opcode and operand (if any).

More information can be found on the [Wikipedia page](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Jens Can't comment due to rep points :(

Comment: My advise always point out to product documentation or reliable pages. I am not saying WIKI isnt relevant but it can edited by anyone... so the authenticity of the content cannot be justified

Comment: You **should** add more meat to your answer... Write something a little more than the one liner you just wrote.

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama I agree, but OP here wants to know how the java compiler works and the wiki page provides a nice idea on that matter.

Comment: The here is something you can use to give more information:[link]http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077233/core-java/bytecode-basics.html?page=1[link]

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama I think that will be too complex for OP.